# Is JQuery Event Methods/Functions synchronize to each others?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im confuse on how the event methods/functions related to each other when they are use at the same time.

For Example:

```
$("#searchInput").blur(function(e) {
   var isClicked = false;
   $("#sresult").click(function(e) {
      isClicked = true;
   });
   if(isClicked) {
      $("#sresult").show(150);
   } else {
      $("#sresult").hide(150);
   }
});
```

The code above shows when I `blur` on the `#searchInput`, it will either *show* `#sresult` when you `click` it or *hide* it when when you did'nt `click` it.

But there is something wrong in my code that I don't know why it keeps hiding even if I clicked the `#sresult`.

Is it that maybe when you click the `#sresult`, the `$("#searchInput").blur(function(e)` is fast enough that he didnt want to wait in `$("#sresult").click(function(e)` to function? are event methods are waiting for each other? are they synchronize? correct me if im wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's likely because clicking on `#sresult` causes another blur for `#searchInput`.

Comment: Start by explaing what exactly you are trying to do with this code. Broken code is not a good substitute for a properly detailed explanation. Nesting event listeners inside other event handlers is a bad practice also unless you fully understand the event sequences and the consequences of compounding listeners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Problem

It's important to understand what `.blur()` and `.click()` functions really do. They attach event listeners to a certain element. (Better use `.on()` btw)

### The Explanation

To your code: blur fires, prepares a variable and attaches another event listener. as the if-else statement is also in the blur callback it's executed immediately and thus not waiting for the click, meaning `isClicked` will never be true.

Using nested event listeners is almost never a good idea, you just saw why in your own case.

### The Solution

Am I right with the assumption you're trying to hide a search results field until the search button is clicked? If yes I could help you with code. Though, the easiest approach might be to simply attach a listener for the button and then `.toggle()` the results.

Comment: I don't want to hide the #sresult when I click it, instead I want to hide it only when its onBlur on the #searchInput. Thanks for your answer by the way on your explanation.

Comment: I don't want to hide the #sresult when I click it, instead I want to hide it only when its onBlur on the #searchInput. Thanks for your answer by the way on your explanation.

Comment: Ok, that's a bit deep in the ID of your app, I think your problem's solved though right? :D